# Batch File - Comparing strings as integers not working

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to compare integer folder names to a variable. The folder names are all integer values. For example, in folder "VersionedFolders" exist sub folders "95", "96", up to "100".

My script is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


SET %PATH_TO_VERSION_FOLDER=VersionedFolders
SET %CurrentVersion = 99

for /f %%a in ('dir /B "%PATH_TO_VERSION_FOLDER%"') do (        
    if %CurrentVersion% LEQ %%a (
        echo CurrentVersion !CurrentVersion! is less than or equal to %%a.      
        set CurrentVersion=%%a 
    ) else (
        echo CurrentVersion !CurrentVersion! is not less than or equal to %%a       
    )
)
```

The output is as follows:

```
CurrentVersion 99 is less than or equal to 100.
CurrentVersion 100 is not less than or equal to 95.
CurrentVersion 100 is not less than or equal to 96.
CurrentVersion 100 is not less than or equal to 97.
CurrentVersion 100 is not less than or equal to 98.
CurrentVersion 100 is less than or equal to 99.
```

The last iteration is where the problem exists since 100 > 99.

Note the output of dir /B "%PATH_TO_VERSION_FOLDER%" is

```
100
95
96
97
98
99
```

Any ideas why "if 100 LEQ 99" is returning true?

Comment: Its comparing left to right as a string. 1 < 9 and those are the first characters. If your foldernames had leading 0's, it would sort right.

Comment: @LeeMeador Why does it say both 99 LEQ 100 and 100 LEQ 99?

Comment: your title says, they're being compared as strings, and `1 < 9` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is DELAYED EXPANSION.

When the `for ...%%a...` is parsed, the value of `currentversion` as it stands at that time is substituted into the code.

Use `!currentversion!` to obtain the RUN-TIME value (with delayedexpansion invoked, as you have...)

(Also: to assign a value, use `SET VAR=VALUE` not `SET %VAR=VALUE`)

Comment: (Suspicious question: are you User2554585?)

Comment: Thanks Peter. No, I am not User2554585.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you intended?  You also had spaces in front/behind variables and variable names, which is something to watch for.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET PATH_TO_VERSION_FOLDER=VersionedFolders
SET CurrentVersion=0

for /f %%a in ('dir /B /ad "%PATH_TO_VERSION_FOLDER%"') do (        
    if !CurrentVersion! LEQ %%a (
        echo CurrentVersion !CurrentVersion! is less than or equal to %%a.
    ) else (
        echo CurrentVersion !CurrentVersion! is greater than %%a.
    )
        set CurrentVersion=%%a
)
pause
```